# Default option in select, with reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have one option in my select to filter all my results and list of other options, I can set default option from my list, but cannot set the first mat-option as default. How can I do that?

```
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-12 p-0 pb-2">
    <mat-select formControlName="carControl">
      <mat-option value="0">(All)</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data.filteredListOfCars" [value]="item" ngDefaultControl>
        {{this.codeListService.getNameOfManufacturerById(item.manufacturerId)}} {{item.model}} {{item.ecv}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I am setting default value like this

```
selectValueInControl(){
    this.filterFormGroup.get('statusControl').setValue(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[value]="0"` instead of `value="0"`

```
<mat-option [value]="0">(All)</mat-option>
```